# How to add while loop in my code?

Tags: web3.py, python

How i can make my code work after its done? like i want to make my code start again and again when its done.

````
#Setup the PancakeSwap contract
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=router_address, abi=PancakeABI)
 
nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
 
start = time.time()
print(web3.toWei('0.03','ether'))

pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
  0, # here setup the minimum destination token you want to have, you can do some math, or you can put a 0 if you don't want to care
  [spend,contract_id],
  sender_address,
  (int(time.time()) + 1000000)
).buildTransaction({
  'from': sender_address,
  'value': web3.toWei(0.4,'ether'),#This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
  'gas': 250000,
  'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5','gwei'),
  'nonce': nonce,
})

 
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=private)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(tx_token))```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    your code here
```